# What is serial voting and how is it handled?

Tags: discussion

I was logged in in Beta a while ago and then suddenly I got 200 reputations (which really surprised me 'cause I haven't posted any questions or answers lately to get that high of a score from but undeniably, I got happy :D -___-). I don't know where I got that score but then I shrugged it off and let it be like that (who would not? lol) And then a bit later, I got a notification saying

> -200 Serial upvoting reversed

then I lost the 200 reputation I gained a while back. I was thinking what the heck happened and I'm almost losing my cool ('cause losing 200 reputations is a bit displeasing). And then my sister admitted that she used one of my email account to log in into Anime & Manga, logged out my account (using gmail and yes, I have two email accounts) and that she posted an answer and a question and upvoted almost all of my answers and question,s also to gain the "Suffrage" badge. And then I realized what the **Serial upvoting reversed** meant.

So, I just want to ask how the moderator handles the serial upvoting? Will the user's decision to upvote a certain user's answers and questions consecutively be disregarded? What are the rules pertaining to this?